# Format label and toggle switch on same line in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to find the Javascript equivalent of creating the following html element:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="slider">Select slider:</label>
<select name="slider" id="slider" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

This puts the label on the same line.

Here is my attempt, but the label sits underneath the toggle switch.  I don't know the JQuery method for formatting the data-role="fieldcontain" div.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ckHr/13/

HTML

```
<div data-role="content" id="content">
</div>
```

JS

```
$('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label>Label</label><select class="flip" name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider"><option value="off">Off</option><option value="on">On</option></select></div>').appendTo($("#content"));

$(".flip").slider();

$('<button id="submit">Submit</button>').appendTo($("#content")).button();

$(document).delegate("#submit", "vclick", function() { alert($("#flip-1").val()); });
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what is that you want?

Comment: Sorry, edited post to make it clearer.  In the pure HTML version, the label is inline with the toggle-switch.  In the mixed version, the label sits underneath the toggle-switch.

Comment: Use `ui-grid` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2ckHr/16/

Comment: If all else fails, you can always give the label an inline style when you create it... `$('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label style="vertical-align:1em">Jauhar` etc.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest, inline way, is to add some CSS to the label:

```
<label for="slider" style="display: inline; vertical-align: 1.2em;">Select slider:</label>
```

this can be factored in a CSS class, minding display override:

```
 .switchlabel { display: inline !important; vertical-align: 0.8em; }
```

If calculating `vertical-align` value is not feasible, you have to change styles after control creation. You have to add `vertical-align: middle;` to this element (created by jQuery Mobile):

```
<div role="application" class="ui-slider ui-slider-switch ...
```